# Redirecting www to non www in subfolder

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, no-www, subdirectory

I have Joomla installed on root folder and another Joomla installed on a subfolder.
I want to redirect `www` to `no-www` in subfolder by this code in blog *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$2 [R=301,L]
```

It worked for root redirect but when I want browse internal page it redirect the page to home page.

Comment: You use `$2` in place of `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `.htaccess` inside your subfolder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```